# linq grouping with recent record

Tags: c#, linq, grouping

[image: I have an sql table with data like this]

This is my History table that keeps track of each PERSON’s status in given time.
I want to group this in such a way that Group it by Update_date .  and get the COUNT of  status_id. Also If a person has more than one status change within the Group , take the most recent Status change. ( see row with id=5, that should be ignored as same person has more recent status change)

[image]

I have been trying this with different Linq nested statements and yet not successful.

```
       var aa = _DatabaseContext.VAHistories
            .GroupBy(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("dy", a.update_date))
            .Select(g => new
                {
                    Name = g.Key,
                    Status0= g.Where(c => c.status_id == 0).GroupBy(gg => gg.person_id).Select(c => c.Max(m => m.update_date)).Count(),
                    Status1= g.Where(c => c.status_id == 1).GroupBy(gg => gg.person_id).Select(c => c.Max(m => m.update_date)).Count(),
                    Status2= g.Where(c => c.status_id == 2).GroupBy(gg => gg.person_id).Select(c => c.Max(m => m.update_date)).Count(),
                    Status4= g.Where(c => c.status_id == 4).GroupBy(gg => gg.person_id).Select(c => c.Max(m => m.update_date)).Count(),
                    Status3= g.Where(c => c.status_id == 5).GroupBy(gg => gg.person_id).Select(c => c.Max(m => m.update_date)).Count()

                }

                ).ToList<object>();
        return aa;
```

This gives something close, but the problem is it does not take care of each person's latest status update. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have already written the necessary code, but just put it in the wrong place. You need to apply requirement about latest change per person at first, and then proceed with date grouping etc.

Initial filtering can be done by this code:

```
GroupBy(gg => gg.person_id).Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(m => m.update_date).First())
```

applied to the whole set of records.

All in all try doing the following:

```
var aa = _DatabaseContext.VAHistories
    .GroupBy(gg => gg.person_id).Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(m => m.update_date).First())
    .GroupBy(a => SqlFunctions.DatePart("dy", a.update_date))
    .Select(g => new
            {
                Name = g.Key,
                Status0= g.Where(c => c.status_id == 0).Count(),
                Status1= g.Where(c => c.status_id == 1).Count(),
                Status2= g.Where(c => c.status_id == 2).Count(),
                Status4= g.Where(c => c.status_id == 4).Count(),
                Status3= g.Where(c => c.status_id == 5).Count()

            })
    .ToList<object>();
```

Comment: a.update_date in line 3  is giving error. ( red color in VS2010)

Comment: with .first() it gives an error. but .firstordefault() it is working. However I'll have to check if the result is as what I expect. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need just the records which match the date in the key.

```
var groupedData = (from h in _DatabaseContext.VAHistories
        group h by new { h.Date } into g1
        select new {
          Name = g1.Key,
          Status0 = g1.Count(hd => hd.Date == g1.Key && hd.Status_id = 0),
          Status1 = g1.Count(hd => hd.Date == g1.Key && hd.Status_id = 1),
          Status2 = g1.Count(hd => hd.Date == g1.Key && hd.Status_id = 2),
          Status3 = g1.Count(hd => hd.Date == g1.Key && hd.Status_id = 3),
          Status4 = g1.Count(hd => hd.Date == g1.Key && hd.Status_id = 4),
        }).ToList();

return groupedData;
```